# How to inform English language users about useful English language resources?

Tags: feature-request, site-faq

I want to be able to use ELU.SE to help promote proper usage of the English language (in specific: synonyms, definitions, and spelling).  How can [this link](http://www.google.com/help/features.html#keyword) (below) be added into the **FAQ** section to let users know how to improve their English language skills?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- for your title question there are:

  - [List of English Language Tools](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1482/what-are-your-favorite-english-language-tools) (random useful things)
  - [General References](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/list-of-general-references) (where to go when a question is closed as 'general reference'
- For your first sentence,  ELU is populated more by descriptivists than by people who want to enforce prescriptivist standards. Which I would say is actually better. The people you inform will get more than just a standard answer but also the variants by region and formality. But more often than not, you'll get a single answer for just one variety or one level of formality and not necessarily the 'standard' one. Also, there is more than one standard, and even within a standard there is disagreement. So you might get that nuance or not. What I'm saying there's no guarantee here of getting the 'right' answer.
- For that link in particular, I'd say it would go best in the 'General Reference' question I just mentioned. And you can go edit it yourself. Since you don't have a lot of rep yet, it won't automatically get edited, but a high rep person can approve the edit.

  - but in general, to add something to the FAQ, start a question here (specifically about the edit) and a moderator might be convinced to edit it (normal users can't).

Comment: Thank you Mitch.