# Update the "list of community recommended resources"

Tags: discussion, on-topic-off-topic, general-reference

Quoting from the [help center:](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

> #### Where can I find answers to simple and basic questions?
>
> If your question is simple and can probably be easily answered by
> looking it up, then you may find common online internet resources to
> be of some help. View our [list of community recommended resources](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1482/what-are-your-favorite-english-language-tools) to
> find some that may be of help to you.

The link currently leads to a question on the main site, that is currently closed as off-topic by RedDwight♦ (and rightly so).

The question is not historically locked (even though there's a moderator comment indicating so). Additionally another comment leads to meta:

> More organized on meta: [List of general references](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/list-of-general-references) - Andrew Grimm

I suggest the help center should link directly to the meta question.  Why? because the meta is there for defining of topic. Not some nevermore changing list-question on the main site.

Comment: Neither list is supposed to be "definitive" in respect of what used to be classed as General Reference for the purpose of closevoting, so I don't think it's particularly important that the one on "main" can't accept additional answers. In some ways I see an *advantage* to the current link in the FAQ - at least the fact that the question is closed makes it abundantly clear *we don't want questions asking for resources*. Not that it stops *all* of them, but it's more of a trickle than a torrent.