# When a question is closed, tell them the procedure for reopening it

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions

> **UPDATE:** [Version 2.1 of the trial](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7913/notes-to-reviewers-trial-version-2-1) is now live. The intention is for the last voter who closes a question to link to the trial in lieu of the link appearing in the notice of closure. Here's a template that can be pasted directly as a comment:

`See [Notes to Reviewers](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7913/142322)`

---

Low-quality questions (LQQ) serve as a disincentive for visitors and regulars to seek or contribute high-quality answers at ELU. We therefore place an LQQ on hold for a grace period, reopening it if it sufficiently improves and deleting it if not. The OP of a closed question should bear the onus of proof that their edits make their questions worth reconsidering, but in practice, that burden falls almost exclusively on reviewers.

On the other hand, on-hold notices can appear final to visitors. It can feel off-putting to find that the community deems one's posts unworthy of attention. Closing a question is *objectively* an invitation to improve the question, but invitations should sound like "here's where to go and what to do" rather than "go away until you improve". The OP may make a case on the meta site for reopening, but they are only told the policy if they ask.

The [core](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/28156148#28156148) of this feature request is to address both issues by giving the **OP** of a closed question some transparency and guidance about the process of reopening their question. This is an explicit invitation to (re)engage to have their posted question answered. It also helps **reviewers** of the reopen queue: it's easier, less frustrating and more accurate to read what the OP thinks s/he did to improve the question than it is for *each* reviewer to piece the clues together from edit trails and comment trails. Here's the gist of what I'm suggesting should be on the close/on-hold notice:

> After editing your question, please note in comments or [notes to reviewers (link)] how your edits improve the question. Your question will be reopened if it gains 5 reopen votes.

In the worst case, OP behaviour doesn't change at all. However, the improvement to the quality of our ELU process, namely, greater transparency of the reopen process, is justification enough to expand the boiler-plate notices.

In the best case, the OP raises their own question to a high quality and stay on to contribute, so we have a better site *and* feel welcoming to good company.

Note: *The previous version of this feature request can be found [here](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/7795/10)*.

Comment: When a closed question has been edited, doesn't it show up on the review queue?

Comment: @MετάEd Yes, it does. The problem is that edits sometimes don't tell the whole story - there may need to be an accompanying appeal *about* the edits. More to the point, this request is geared towards changing *OP* behaviour rather than changing *reviewer* behaviour.

Comment: Hi, Lawrence, I fully understand where you are coming from about this issue. But remember this. We have so many Original Posters all around the word who don't know what *edit* means or don't understand what the close reason is for. I don't want this Meta site swamped with requests for re-opening. Most of them are just one-off users about whom we don't have to care so much. If they spend more time, they will be able to ask a better-researched question. If not, what else can we do? They are on their own.

Comment: @Lawrence I agree with Rathony. If there's going to be a change to the notice simply let the user know the question will be reopened if a post-edit peer review leads to enough reopen votes.

Comment: @Rathony That's a good point. Instead of pointing to meta (which, incidentally, *is* the advice we give to those who ask), we could start a special-purpose chat-room for reopen requests. This would let us keep meta for more serious discussion. What do you think?

Comment: So I'm saying I don't disagree with the idea of providing more transparency but I also don't like the idea of a million appeals to meta.

Comment: @MετάEd Ok, how about the [idea](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/7795/when-a-question-is-closed-tell-them-what-the-procedure-is-for-reopening?noredirect=1#comment31936_7795) of appealing to an *appeals* chat room instead?

Comment: @MετάEd By the way, I like your idea about noting the peer-reviewed reopen process in the close / on-hold notice.

Comment: For what it's worth, the standard process worked in the case of the "make a meal out of something" question. In its original form, the question was obviously off-topic enough that 4 high-rep users and a mod VtC within minutes, but at the same time offering comments offering clear & professional explanations of why the question didn't adhere to the norms of the site.  Thereafter, the OP came back and read those comments, reacted to them in good faith, asked for further clarifications with comments, was directed to edit his question, did so, and now the Q is in good shape & has 3/5 reopen votes.

Comment: @DanBron On the other hand, the rat question didn't get a single close vote after 2 days. Both were summarily closed (by a moderator) after I asked about the inconsistency in chat - that wasn't my intent when asking, but still ... . Posting the process in the on-hold notice will encourage VtC for some who are reluctant to close questions that technically do breach the rules about research but that show thought and significant effort otherwise.

Comment: @Lawrence Yes, my comment wasn't intended to offer a counterpoint to your suggestion (which I like, as I like all tools that automate a repetitive task I otherwise have to perform manually). Rather, the only concern I have about your feature-request is that it will prove ineffective, for the reasons you identified: when most OPs see "*... [on hold]*" or "*... [closed]*" they stop reading (and, in many cases, start arguing). But as you said there are some conscientious OPs out there who take feedback in the good faith under which it is offered, and your suggestion will improve their experience.

Comment: @DanBron Case in point (regarding my previous comment): [how do you say the university or school people graduated from in one word or phrase?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/312844/how-do-you-say-the-university-or-school-people-graduated-from-in-one-word-or-phr).

Comment: @DanBron Agreed. Those are the very people that we want to encourage to stay.

Comment: I like the idea of mentioning how to go about getting a question reopened in the close notice. I also agree that meta may not be the best recommendation. However, I don't agree with the suggestion that a chat should be the procedure. Perhaps closed questions could be added to the reopen queue on closure, or another queue created?

Comment: @JEL: closed questions already get added to the reopen queue once they are edited. I don't think they need to go there before then.

Comment: @sumelic, "once they are edited" is the sticking point. I'm a compulsive editor, so it wouldn't have stuck me in any case, but I did participate for quite a while before I learned there was an established and sanctioned, although informally sanctioned, procedure for reopening closed questions beyond editing them. Editing the question seemed to be a not very certain way to have the question reopened. That led to it seeming to be a 'no recourse' situation if your question was closed. The situation didn't encourage participation.

Comment: @JEL Thanks for the in-principle support. I think we all prefer LQQ posters to improve their *own* questions. Adding questions immediately to any queue upon closure puts the effort back onto the community, not the OP. What do you see as the problems with an appeals chat site?

Comment: @Law, I'm not sure how the mechanism would work. I know I abhor chat, but that aside, what happens when a person whose question is closed goes to a 'reopen' chat: are there already...uh...chatters there? How would the chat attract participants other than those who've been referred to it by the close notice?

Comment: @JEL Yes, for this to work, it will need several high-rep users to visit the appeals chat room regularly. Perhaps the mods could visit from time to time, but I'm not prepared to *ask* them to add this to their workload. If this request is approved, I'll volunteer to visit regularly for the first couple of months. It just takes one person to vote to reopen and add a positive comment to the question for the question to get a good hearing in the usual review queue, so if we have even a small number visiting regularly to review reopen requests, the idea has a chance of succeeding.

Comment: Thanks for the `featured` tag, Ms Fox!

Comment: @Law, as you say, I support this in principle. My necessary laziness and various low tolerances suggest I won't participate directly. It seems as if most, if not all of what you're suggesting could be done by you (along with anybody else interested). You can make the chat room (I think--I've never tried), people it, etc. For the changes to the close notices, until the idea is proven (how I don't know) or gains traction, you can add the reopen chat room verbiage to a custom comment, rather than embedding it in the standard notices.

Comment: @JEL I don't think it would be appropriate for me to do this as a one-man band. Those are good ideas though, a good starting point to get things going if the basic idea has enough support.

Comment: Note: I'm editing the request for clarity, and adding another suggestion: to create a **single** meta 'question' where each reopen request is an 'answer'. When done, I'll either post another comment delete this comment.

Comment: The feature-request edit is done.

Comment: @JEL Just a note to say that I've changed the suggested 'appeals court' location to a *single* meta question, with each appeal a separate 'answer'. This avoids LQQ-smearing of one-meta-Q-per-appeal and the admin overheads of a dedicated chat room.

Comment: @Lawrence, those seem to be excellent refinements of the proposal, and they lend themselves to individual action. To reiterate what I imagine you're proposing: you would post a question on meta titled something to the effect of "Why should your question be reopened?" In the question would be explicit instructions (e.g., 1. edit your question to address concerns; 2. answer this question, including details of how you've improved the question; 3. etc.). Then on close notices or in comments, link to that meta question: "if you would like your question reopened, answer this [linked meta question]."

Comment: @JEL Exactly. :)

Comment: Are you waiting for a critical mass of upvotes on this? Why not just do it and see if it gains traction?

Comment: @JEL I've been playing with some ideas mentally and have just started typing up / working on the 'appeals' question. Subject to other commitments IRL, I hope to have a meta question up as a trial in the next couple of days that we can link to from questions we vote to close. Full implementation may also require mod involvement to edit the notices, and it would be good in any case to get some feedback from the mods about the proposal. (Unless she says otherwise, I'll take Kit Z. Fox's `featured` tag as support from a mod.)

Comment: Is there some sample text for the last close-voter to use?

Comment: @Marthaª I ended up just going with "About reopening questions", with the whole phrase linked. Good idea about sample text - I've added this to the update as a template.

Comment: Test of copy-paste template: [About reopening questions](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/7839/142322)

Answer (score 3):

*Note: this (below) is the text I intend to post as the 'appeals court' meta question. Before taking that as a unilateral step, however, I'm posting it here first for a few days for community editing and comments. The next step would be to post the meta question as a live trial, during which users can link to it from comments when voting to close a question.*

***UPDATE*** The [trial](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7839/please-consider-reopening-my-question-trial) is now online.

---

Title: Please consider reopening my question. [Trial]

---

*Original meta discussion: [When a question is closed, tell them the procedure for reopening it](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7795/142322). Please use that question to discuss the procedure below. Answers to this question should only consist of appeals to reopen specific questions.*

---

If your question has been closed, it means that Stack Exchange's English Language and Usage community has voiced an opinion that your question wasn't quite ready for prime time yet. Questions can be closed for many reasons. In each case, the main reason will be shown on the notice that appears on your closed question. There's a simple procedure to ask to reopen your question:

> **Edit your question to meet the site's requirements.**

This will automatically put the question into a review queue, where it will be reopened if 5 reviewers (or one moderator) vote for reopening. If you think the reviewers have missed or dismissed your improvements, this page is a place where you can explain why your question should be reopened.

Before we go into specifics, here are two general guidelines:

- **Your question must be clear**. People should be able to look at your question and immediately know what you are asking.
- **Your question must be clearly answerable**. It should be possible to answer your question fully, within a reasonable space.

### Basic Steps

**Address the concerns on the close/on-hold notice.** For example,

- if your question is claimed to be a duplicate of another question, read the linked question and its answers. Sometimes, the link of duplicates may include several questions (yours links to theirs, which links to another, etc). Read them all, then if you still think your question is different, edit your question to refer to those questions and explain why.
- if your question involves a single-word-request or similar tag, follow the detailed instructions in the tag's info (hover over the tag and click 'info'). Quite often, the only thing lacking is a sample sentence to show what part of speech you want. Edit your question to follow the extensive guidelines.

**Look up general references yourself** and edit your question to report what you have found, then explain why you are not satisfied with what you have found. This helps the community to directly address the actual problem. Here are some collections to consider:

- [What good reference works on English are available?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available)
- [Dictionaries](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2574/142322) - an important part of the above. There are links to dictionaries for words, idioms, pronunciation and more.
- [What are your favorite English language tools?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/1482/142322)
- [Search the ELU archive for answers to similar questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/search) - this page also includes tips on conducting advanced searches.

### Further Steps

If the above isn't enough to get your question reopened, try explaining here why you think it should be reopened.

**Explain what you have done by adding an answer to this question.**

- Add an answer to this question. This will bring the question to the attention of people on the meta site (note: don't add a whole new question on the meta site to ask for your question to be reopened - that's what this page is for).
- In your answer, summarise what you have done and include a link to your question. You can get the link by clicking the `share` button under *your* question.
  [image]
- Answer any issues that the community may raise.

**Link to the answer you just posted.**

- Click the `share` button under your answer, and copy the link that pops up.
- Go to your closed question and add the following comment: **`[I have made a request to reopen this question.](xyz)`**, replacing "xyz" with the link you copied from the `share` button.
- Include the square brackets and round brackets exactly as shown. This adds a link in your comments to the reopen request you've just made, which makes it easier for reviewers to see why you think your question should be reopened.

See you on the other side!

Comment: The first draft is posted above. I'm sure there are many improvements that can be made - please contribute via comments below, separate answers, or direct edits of the above. I'll act as editor-in-chief for this answer for now, though if any mod would prefer to take over, just let me know. I hope this process will produce something that most of us will be happy to adopt. In a week's time, let's say, I'll post the result (sans header comment) as *the* 'appeals court' meta question for a live trial. The notices will stay the same, but we can link to the 'appeals court' from closed questions. ...

Comment: If (when?) the mods are happy with the result, it'll be up to them to conclude the trial by making appropriate changes to the notices.

Comment: The above will work very well for users who are strongly motivated and/or passionate about the English language in the first place. But seeing as they already are, they're the ones who took the time to read the help center in the first place. For non-native speakers who lack confidence, such a detailed text is overwhelming. And what's more, I don't think it will make one jot of difference to users who are simply saying "gimme the answer".

Comment: I'm a strong believer that if you can see a "good" or "valid" question in a post that has been put on hold, then edit the OP. Show how it's done without changing the original question. If necessary provide support and the research. Some of the simplest questions in EL&U's database produced top notch answers. We need to recapture those users, the ones who have abandoned EL&U.

Comment: Hi @Mari-LouA, thanks for your comments. I was (and still am) also concerned about length, but thought I'd put it up anyway so others can have a look and help improve it. The motivated ones you mention *are* the ones we want to keep. For the *gimme*s, a documented reopen process listed on the page would encourage me to VtC more. Since the visible change is just a couple of extra sentences on the notice, it shouldn't discourage people from making more specific constructive comments to the OP.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I'm not a linguist or etymologist; an enthusiast perhaps. But I believe that the primary glue at ELU (i.e. why people stay and not just 'buy and bye') is the interaction of this community that has grown up around a shared interest in English. To a certain extent, building the site depends on building the community. I'll admit that this is a small step, but I think it's a step in the right direction. Still, I'm all ears if you have other ideas about recapturing those excellent ELU participants of the past.

Comment: Part of the problem, and this is a phenomenon I have experienced whenever I have joined an online community, is EL&U's popularity. The larger the community base, the more quality suffers.  I'm going to sound elitist, but I don't care because what I'm saying is the truth. It happened with Google plus, Stumbleupon, Answers.com, Reddit, Twitter etc...

Comment: The number of top contributors is shrinking compared to the number of LQ questions and LQ answers submitted daily. The same thing is happening to Stack Overflow, it is flooded with LQQ questions, its clawing desperately to retain its reputation as one of the best Q&A sites.  But it's a losing battle...

Comment: Thanks @Rathony. I suppose we're guessing at their responses either way, but I'd like to reiterate that I'm **not** trying to make it easier to reopen questions - I want to make it clearer *how* this community wants OPs to go about it. If this approach would encourage me to VtC more, perhaps it would encourage others to do so as well. Those who view VtC as quality control of the accept/reject variety would then see more LQQ closures, and those who view VtC as an invitation for OPs to improve their own questions would feel freer to do so. (cont'd)

Comment: On the LQQ-OP's side (excuse the acronyms), those that don't care would go elsewhere quickly and without too much argy-bargy via comments. Those that do care about getting their questions answered self-select by following the reopen process.

Comment: I apologise for sounding such a wet blanket, or the voice of doom, just call me Cassandra from now on :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA I think you're among the "users who are strongly motivated and/or passionate about the English language" that you mentioned :) . ELU would be a poorer place without you, Rathony or other *currently* active ELU members. (cont'd)

Comment: @Mari-LouA The content of my reply to Rathony applies to your point about popularity as well, so I'll just incorporate it by reference. I think the 3 of us (among others) want similar outcomes, that is, to maintain / increase the quality of questions, answers and - for me at least - community interaction on ELU, though perhaps via different means. My invitation to suggest other means wasn't rhetorical; no need to apologise. Although I think this feature request is a good approach (of course, or I wouldn't be suggesting it :) ), I'm interested to hear other approaches as well. (cont'd)

Comment: @Mari-LouA (Rathony and any others also) Do you have any constructive suggestions regarding this proposed 'appeals forum' draft?

Comment: Thanks @Rathony. Let's see how it goes :) .

Comment: @Lawrence I will delete my comments as they seem to be off-topic and to clear them for other suggestions. Good luck.

Comment: I take issue with "...Other than generic web searches...". **We do not expect users to Google their question.** The unvetted, confusing results returned by a generic web search is precisely what this site is intended to REPLACE. What we **do** expect and require is that they **use the effing dictionary**. (And/or thesaurus.) I don't know if we currently expect/require it, but searching *this site* should probably also be among the first thing you do before posting a new question. But a generic web search is explicitly *not* required.

Comment: @Marthaª Thanks for the clarification. I didn't realise that generic web searches were explicitly not required. It's now removed. Good point about dictionaries - they are included in the *reference works* link but I agree that they deserve their own entry here (now added).

Comment: It's been about a day since the last comment on this question. I've made some small changes and will leave it up for another day or so. If there are no further requests to change by then, I'll take this to the live trial.

Comment: @Marthaª I'd like to draw further on your experience with ELU. It seems that **neologisms**, popular in questions, are at the heart of proof-reading as a reason to close. More generally, I've picked up (perhaps wrongly) that there's a generalised sentiment that ELU is *not* about **inventing phrases**. Would it be overstating the site's position to add a third *general guideline* that says, "Your question must be about *established* uses of English"? (Needless to say, but I'd welcome comments about this from others also.)

Comment: I don't know if we have, or need, any explicit policy against neologisms. We discourage "name my class variable" type questions (which are often the ones that want a neologism), simply because there's no single correct answer. (Unfortunately, users have noticed this and do their best to lie about why they need their very-specific-meaning-but-made-up-is-OK word.) Other bad questions of this ilk also tend to fall under one of the close reasons.

Comment: @Marthaª It's not just programming - there are also those "tell me what to say in this situation" types of questions. I get the feeling that standard phrases (quotes or google/ngram hits) are fine, but unconventional phrasing may get an answer down-voted or at least a cautionary comment. But maybe these are isolated cases, so I'll just leave it out of the proposed post. Thanks for sharing your thoughts on this.

Answer (score 0):

## Trial Version 2.1

*As before, I'll leave this up for a few days for comments and improvements before taking it live. I'd like to incorporate some of the lessons learnt from the trial so far.*

---

Title: Notes to Reviewers

---

*English Language & Usage* (ELU) is a community for etymologists, linguists and English enthusiasts. As a Stack Exchange community, ELU shares Stack Exchange's goal to *build libraries of high-quality questions and answers, focused on each community's area of expertise*.

Questions should be asked within ELU's [areas of interest](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) and answers should be definitive. This imposes a level of expectation to carefully state the question. It may include noting aspects of the question that are *not* of interest, how far you've got, or carefully highlighting the *core* of the question.

When the expectation isn't met, the question may be put on hold as [an invitation to edit for improvement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10583/286574). Once edited, your question is automatically queued for review. It will be reopened if 5 reviewers vote for reopening. **This page is for you to make brief notes to reviewers to assist the review process**, similar to [that at Math.SE](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19042/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-etc-volume-01-2015-current-versio).

1. Read [this page](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/24861) for some **excellent tips on how to ask questions**, including [examples of good questions and a simple pattern for asking good questions](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/465/24861).
2. **Edit your question**, paying attention to the concerns listed on the close/on-hold notice. Here are some general references that may help:

   - [What good reference works on English are available?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available)
   - [Dictionaries](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2574/142322) - an important part of the above. There are links to dictionaries for words, idioms, pronunciation and more.
   - [What are your favorite English language tools?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/1482/142322)
   - [Search the ELU archive for answers to similar questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/search) - this page also includes tips on conducting advanced searches.
3. You can add **notes for reviewers** by placing a comment on your own question. You may also record your notes in a new answer here and link the answer to your question as follows:

   - In your answer, include a link to your question. Click `share` under your question for the link.
   - Add the comment **`[Notes to reviewers](xyz)`** to your question to show reviewers where to look. Keep the square brackets and round brackets as shown, but replace `xyz` with a link to your answer. Click `share` under your answer for the link.

Comment: It's been a couple of days with no comments or objections, so I'm taking this live.

Comment: Version 2.1 posted.

Answer (score -2):

Let's not feed the bear!

This community is surrounded by many hungry bears who don't want to hunt to feed themselves. Also, I found some bears who complain about our not feeding them quoting a few vague guidelines of our Help Center or a question asked a long time ago when we didn't have those guidelines in place. A few lazy bears don't even respond to comments intended to help write a better question.  We should not welcome those bears. We need to build up more fences and enforce those guidelines more strictly so that those bears could learn what to do to survive here and how to ask a well-researched question with context.

1. [What is the exact definition of the expression 'A Rat's Chance'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/312348/what-is-the-exact-definition-of-the-expression-a-rats-chance)

The OP started the question with "I started to learn English." Then, the OP is a learner. I don't think the question is salvageable. It would be better to leave the following comment:

> If you are a speaker of other languages learning English, I'd like to
>   advise you to visit our sister site [English Language
>   Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/), but please make sure you
>   take the [tour](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit their
>   [Help Center](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help) before posting any
>   question.

2. [Does the expression “make something of a meal out of something” mean essetially “make a meal of something”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/312862/does-the-expression-make-something-of-a-meal-out-of-something-mean-essetially)

As Hotlicks commented, the question is not clear. A full sentence is required. The OP is lazy. What else can we do? The OP seems to be a learner and he should be advised to go to ELL where (s)he belongs. (I close-voted this question.)

Both Original Posters don't seem to belong on English Language and Usage (ELU), but belong on English Language Learners (ELL).

We have a well-established mechanism where a question is placed on a review-queue for reopen vote when it is edited. We will review it and decide. We rarely see a question re-opened while so many questions are being closed everyday. The main reason is almost all those hungry bears don't respond to comments and close reasons. That could mean (1) they are one-off users who don't intend to stay here long, (2) they don't want to bother to edit it and get it reopened (they are not desperate enough), (3) unfortunately, they don't know how it works and they don't even know how closing and re-opening work.

What can we possibly do to those users? I don't think letting them know they can go to Meta or ELU Chat Room to get their questions reopened is as much helpful to those OPs as advising them to edit the post in as much detail or go to ELL.

They should edit their questions and our focus should be on whether they edit their posts properly or not. The beauty of ELU is we are democracy and decision-making process is quite fast, especially for reopening.

I just left a comment (advice to go to ELL) to an OP who asked six questions, five of which were closed. We need to post such a comment more to the OPs who will be welcome and upvoted on ELL while being downvoted and closed on ELU.

Comment: Hi @Rathony, I understand where you're coming from. This isn't feeding the bears - quite the opposite, actually: give the OP an incentive to do their homework, and reassure fence-sitters that hitting the close button isn't being unkind to visitors. I also took on board your earlier comments about not swamping meta. Instead of using the ELU main chat room, the proposal is to open a *new* chat room for appeals (using the main ELU chat would have the same effect as posting on meta). Those who aren't interested in reviewing appeals can simply avoid the appeals chat room.

Comment: @Lawrence Hi, Lawrence. I admire your enthusiasm to help those OPs. Based on my rather short experience, more than 90% of the OPs are one-off users who don't care very much about their questions being closed or down-voted. The OP of the first linked question didn't log in after posting the question. I am sure (s)he will never come back. The second OP logged in later, but is not responding to the comments. There is virtually nothing we can do for them. They need to respond to the comments if they want to get an answer which I think is far more important than letting them know your suggestion.

Comment: Hi @Rathony, yeah, can't win 'em all. Think of my request as site improvement of a different sort :) . If it ends up winning over even just a handful of [linguists, etymologists or enthusiasts](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour), I'd say it would be worth it. The two examples I cited aren't the best showcases, but they did (unknowingly on their part) kick this off. Oh, by the way, we need a better phrase than telling them to *go to ELL* - it's uncomfortably close to telling 'em to *go to 'ell*.

Comment: @Lawrence I absolutely agree with your idea on "explaining to the OP in more detail that they need to edit the post and letting them know the question could be reopened." The problem is we rarely see any OP respond to such a comment in the close reason. Let's see how your idea is implemented. I am not against your idea.

Comment: Strenuously disagree with the premises here. If you're going to throw some poor neophyte into a maze of arbitrational beaureaucracy, it behooves you to at least show them the beginning of the red tape you expect them to follow. This isn't "feeding the bear", it's common courtesy. The aim should be lowering barriers to entry, not the opposite: "build up more fences" is elitist, user-hostile nonsense, seeing new users as "the enemy/bear", rather than something to be welcomed.

Comment: @DewiMorgan I am not sure how long you have been a member of Stack Exchange and how much you know about how it works on English Language and Usage. We have English Language Learners which is exclusively for learners. This site is not for learners. You get that? Spend more time here and see how it works. We are swamped with low-quality questions and we find it very difficult to manage them.

Comment: Hi, I'm a new user. If you assume that all new users are just ELLers, then it's you who have something you don't get: you consider me a bear. This would be why I disagree with your viewpoint so strenuously.

Comment: @DewiMorgan It is up to you. Don't judge a book by its cover. All right?

Comment: Hi @DewiMorgan, glad you could join us. This feature request hopes to address two issues simultaneously. You've picked up on the first, which is that new users should be shown the beginning of the red tape - that's only fair. The second is that too much *jst-gimme-de-answerz* can be distasteful to some. According to your public user profile, you've been around ELU longer than I have, but I'm glad you're keeping an eye onthe needs of the new :) . It's always tricky to balance concerns, and I invite you to visit the other answer to share your thoughts as the proposed process is being drafted.

Comment: @Lawrence Thanks! Already upvoted other answer and Q, but had nothing further to add to them. Compared to the luminaries around here, I consider myself new still: I've little understanding of the red tape hoops, so greatly appreciate this proposal. This answer comes across to me (and I may be misreading it?) as saying we shouldn't follow this proposal as it adds a valuable wall that forces newbie questioners to become fit and able to survive in the wild, or else dump their bodies on ELL as not fit to live. I try never to downvote without an explanatory comment, so left one.