# Notes to Reviewers [Trial, version 2.1]

Tags: discussion, question-closure

*English Language & Usage* (ELU) is a community for etymologists, linguists, and English enthusiasts. As a Stack Exchange community, ELU shares Stack Exchange's goal to *build libraries of high-quality questions and answers, focused on each community's area of expertise*.

Questions should be asked within ELU's [areas of interest](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) and answers should be definitive. This imposes a level of expectation to carefully state the question. It may include noting aspects of the question that are *not* of interest, how far you've got, or carefully highlighting the *core* of the question.

When the expectation isn't met, the question may be put on hold as [an invitation to edit for improvement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10583/286574). Once edited, your question is automatically queued for review. It will be reopened if 5 reviewers vote for reopening. **This page is for you to make brief notes to reviewers to assist the review process**, similar to [that at Mathematics.SE](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19042/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-etc-volume-01-2015-current-versio).

1. Read *[Please, everyone… details](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/24861)* for some **excellent tips on how to ask questions**, including [examples of good questions and a simple pattern for asking good questions](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/465/24861).
2. **Edit your question**, paying attention to the concerns listed on the close/on-hold notice. Here are some general references that may help:

   - [What good reference works on English are available?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available)
   - [Dictionaries](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2574/142322) - an important part of the above. There are links to dictionaries for words, idioms, pronunciation and more.
   - [What are your favorite English language tools?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/1482/142322)
   - [Search the ELU archive for answers to similar questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/search) - this page also includes tips on conducting advanced searches.
3. You can add **notes for reviewers** by placing a comment on your own question. You may also record your notes in a new answer here and link the answer to your question as follows:

   - In your answer, include a link to your question. Click `share` under your question for the link.
   - Add the comment **`[Notes to reviewers](xyz)`** to your question to show reviewers where to look. Keep the square brackets and round brackets as shown, but replace `xyz` with a link to your answer. Click `share` under your answer for the link.

---

*Original meta discussion: [When a question is closed, tell them the procedure for reopening it](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7795/142322). Please use that question to discuss the procedure below. Answers to this question should only consist of notes to reviewers for specific questions.*

Comment: I don't get it. What are you asking for here? What kind of answers do you expect here? I'm looking at the Math.SE one you linked and that just seems like a weird way to deal with what is already handles by the existing mod-tools.

Comment: @Mitch I've put back the link to the original discussion (it's at the bottom of the question now).

Comment: @Mitch The main goal is as a trial for communicating reopen-procedures to OPs of questions that have been put on hold. A secondary goal is to encourage said OPs to make it easier for reviewers to see why a question should be reopened. The ultimate goal of this effort is to improve the quality of ELU questions while fostering a healthy sense of community among like-minded people.

Comment: OK, but I guess I'm slow. I still don't _get_ it. What ... wait... who is this question for, the questioners or the reviewers? Why have one meta-question with a single answer for each closed question? I don't get it. How ...what... this seems complicated...are you saying at the time a question is closed, come here to this meta question, write an explanation? and then give a link to it in a comment on the OP? and who is supposed to do that? the last close voter? The first? A mod?

Comment: @Mitch Let's discuss this on chat. I'll ping you.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thanks for the note. I agree that this should be reopened and have voted accordingly. The [question](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/332324/142322) is interesting because it references an unexpected usage in a headline, where the news is from a well-established organisation. I've left a [comment](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/332324/why-not-an-s-on-speed-in-ukraine-speed-to-test-new-look-germany-defence#comment759328_332324) along similar lines.

Comment: perhaps its best if you deleted your last two comments, since the Q has been reopened. Thank you again for your cooperation.

Comment: @Mari-LouA You're welcome. I'll delete the *at-at* comment, but I think the headlines question can do with the (little bit of) extra attention via my comment link :) . It's also a good example of how this page can be used.