# Closing "what does this mean" questions

Tags: feature-request

Should we add something to the close-vote off topic > proofreading tick-item to include "what does this mean" requests?

To be clear, I'm not suggesting adding a new tick box, just adding to the label of the existing proofreading reason.

Comment: Do you know what *tic* means?

Comment: all right, I'll fix it :-)

Comment: The funny thing is that *tick box* seems to be what they are really called. I had no idea, I just made it up as a description.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think we need another close-reason when we have *general reference*.

"What does this mean" questions should be closed using

> Plese include the research you've done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using [commonly-available references](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available)
>   are off-topic.

It can cover many questions that don't show enough research efforts.

Comment: Also worth pointing out that we only get a limited number (3) of custom close reasons, so they *must* be fairly generic / broadly applicable if they're to be useful. Plus I imagine the people who are too lazy to check a goddamn dictionary are unlikely to be interested in the finer details of why their question is off-topic.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting a new item, Just an expanded label. But I will use the reason indicated in the answer.