# Change the linked references in the help center

Tags: feature-request

In our help center on the [on-topic page](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) the following old ELU-question is linked for references (last section, first paragraph).

[What are your favorite English language tools?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1482)

I would suggest to change that to our meta post which is a lot better curated:

[What good reference works on English are available?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2573)

Comment: How about links to both?

Comment: @Mitch I haven't checked in detail, but it seems to me that the meta post is a more current super-set of what is on the main page.