# Is there a site that you can search for words of the same root/origin of the word you enter?

Tags: discussion, etymology

I'm currently using Online Etymology Dictionary, it mostly tells me how the word evolve from its ancient form to how it looks in modern times rather than tells me other words stemming from the same origin/root.

Is there a site that can show you words base on the same origin or root of whatever word you enter?

Comment: [The AHD Indo-European roots appendix](https://ahdictionary.com/word/indoeurop.html) gives a selection of words that are derived from the same base. But it's just indo-european rroots. I think there is another (smaller) appendix for semitic roots.

Comment: This is a request for resources, which belong on [meta].

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey That is very much under debate.

Comment: @curiousdannii I know, however, for now, the policy is move to meta.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

**[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.com)** gives all words from the root -- as well as nearby words / related searches. It also has a History and Origin section for entries.

For more information on other related resources online see the comprehensive meta thread here:

- [What good reference works on English are available?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available)