# Advice for a book for English Syntax

Tags: discussion, resources

I want a book for English Syntax, I want you to know that I am an elementary student of English Language and I have finished the book "Essential Grammar in Use (A self study reference and practice book for elementary students of English)", Raymond Murphy, Cambridge University Press.

At the end of this book I encountered some problems in understanding some basic syntax notions. I understand of course what is the subject, object, verbs in simple phrases but when I face something more complex (two phrases in one) I have a little misunderstanding, so I want to freshen some things and to extend my knowledge about syntax.

So can anyone suggest a book?

Comment: Although we have a main-site tag, resource requests are not a good fit for Stack Exchange because answers tend to go out of date very quickly, and they aren't really on-topic on the main site: such questions are not about the **English language.** We do have resource questions and suggestions on Meta, though.

Comment: @Andrew We do, but we shouldn't. Meta isn't a place just for breaking rules...

Comment: I think certain resource questions can be on topic on Meta but they should be about resources to aid the main site or aid questions/answers. I don't think requests for pure personal gain should be considered on-topic for Meta.

Comment: Read [McCawley 1998](https://books.google.com/books?id=k6-C5AWWqjQC&pg=PA11&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=3#v=onepage&q&f=false). It's not simple, because syntax is not simple, but it has all the information. However, it will be helpful if you have a native speaker of English available so you can ask them about grammaticality judgements.

Comment: @curiousdannii While that's true, I say we should allow resource requests on meta if the requested resources help in asking or answering questions on main site. Like Hank said, requests for pure personal gains should be off topic.

Comment: I agree with @NVZ. If visitors/members cannot ask about english language and usage reference books _anywhere_ on English Language & Usage site, we should nominate ourselves for the 2017 _Nattering Nabobs of Negativism_ award. // ... As I understand it, most reference requesters can be referred to the excellent [community-curated list of reference books](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available) here on meta.