# free online etymological dictionary with good coverage of details

Tags: discussion, etymology, reference

Currently I use www.etymonline.com but this reference does not show details. For example [prefix pro-](https://www.etymonline.com/word/pro-) in the meaning of "in place of" comes from Latin prō- (and not pro-)

Comment: 1) Get filthy rich.  2) Buy the rights to some etymological dictionary you like.  3) Have it made available online for free.

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Main_Page) has good coverage of the languages that are important for English etymology, although it's not without errors (honestly, though, I think few dictionaries are).

Comment: @sumelic . at least [in this case](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pro-#Etymology_1)  is not good enough.

Comment: It works best if you follow the links, rather than just looking at the article about the English word. The [Wiktionary article on the Latin word "pro"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pro#Latin) tells you the vowel length and gives some further information about the etymology.

Comment: Etymonline is the best free online resource. It takes most of its material from the OED which is the best resource overall; it is online and is accessible for free online with a library card in most of the US and UK. Wiktionary is a work in progress; there will be good parts and not so good parts.

Comment: Also see the dictionary section of the [big link to online resources](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available/2574#2574)