# Other words for 'said'?

Tags: discussion, questions

Okay, I admit; I like quotative verbs. Of course, I would prefer to avoid using 'said' all the time.

AFAIK there is no canonical question asking for *general* alternatives to 'said'. I've compiled quite a list (over 400 so far), and am wondering, would it be interesting to "ask" a question to turn into a community wiki collecting verbs that can be (ab)used as quotatives?

(Or, is there such a question already that I haven't found?)

Comment: Questions asking for lists tend to be closed for being off-topic. I don't think there is any post on EL&U asking for an extensive list of reporting verbs.

Comment: Though it surely is of interest to ELUers, SE is not a good place for reference lists. I've seen things like this on Wikipedia, though it might seem weird there too.

Comment: Right, that's a) why I asked about asking, first, and b) why, if I did it, it would be a "share your knowledge" post (i.e. has an answer already when it goes live) and a community wiki. There *are* some "questions" of that nature floating around SE, but maybe more on meta than the main networks. (Perhaps ironically, Andrew linked to one such...)

Answer (score 5):

What you're asking about is compiling a thesaurus. They already exist, and are in the list of [reference works which should be consulted](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available).

While lists are not expressly mentioned in the [Help](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), they do fit into one of the unwelcome categories:

> To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where …
>
> - every answer is equally valid

I don't recommend asking such a question. (But asking **about** asking the question is entirely the right thing to do.)

Comment: It's not, strictly speaking, a thesaurus, as the focus is words usable *in a specific context*, and not words with similar meaning. I've *gleaned* many of them from thesaurus searches, but in my experience, a thesaurus search will sometimes have a mix of words that are and are not usable as quotatives.

Comment: @Matthew It's thesauricalish. THere are a few entries in Roget's original that just seem to be him listing off 'things that might be used in place of', like synonyms for dying: kick the bucket, buy the farm, off to meet one's maker, etc etc.

Comment: A good start would be Arnold Zwicky's 1971 article "In a Manner of Speaking" (_Linguistic Inquiry_ 2:223-33), which discusses the _snap, cackle,_ and _pipe up_ speech manner verbs.