# Why aren’t my questions being answered

Tags: discussion, questions

If you look at at profile https://english.stackexchange.com/users/373235/theguradian my questions weren’t answered at all.

I assumed that my questions fit the requirements.

Where did I go wrong, and why do I hurt this site?

I need to know how to properly contribute to this site please help.

Comment: I answered your question "Is *it was the birth of a revolution* a metaphor?", and I see your request for *Words that express surprise disdain anger etc*, before it was closed, had several comments, including dozens of suggestions. I haven't looked at all your other conferences but your two questions in Philosophy were certainly answered. I haven't seen you *accept* an answer though.

Comment: One was a request for a list of words and showed no signe of reasonable research. One was infelicitous (most words used as interjections are non-religious; they may, admittedly, not be the ones most often used). The underlying question was arguably only open to opinion ('_why_ do people often choose to use blasphemies?') and/or more philosophy/ethics than language-orientated.

Comment: @Old Brixtonian And I'm afraid I can't condone your answering a question lacking any signs of research (in this case, information is very easily accessible) and (if it were felt that the research did not fully answer the question) far more suitable on ELL.

Comment: As pointed out, starting a question with a false premise is not a good way to get an answer from people who know it's false. Your questions are too broad, too peremptory, too ignorant. Read a book or two on linguistics; don't believe everything you read on the net. Then come back with questions that show some effort on your part before you ask for some on ours.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why you edited your question, but Matt's answer still stands.

Comment: Uhhh To get upvotes

Comment: I need them I’m basically soft banned

Comment: Note that Meta votes have no bearing on Main-site votes (which is just as well here). In order to get unbanned on the Main site, you need to improve the Main-site questions so that the new versions gain upvotes. Drawing attention to them without doing that is likely only to make the situation worse. Have a look at [this similar question](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15140/), its answer and the comments on that.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'll try and help by reviewing some of your questions and pointing out what might be putting people off from answering them.

Let's start with [Why are most interjections a variation of God/Jesus’ name?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/536310/why-are-most-interjections-a-variation-of-god-jesus-name)

It presupposes that most interjections are a variation on God/Jesus' name. This is not true. Starting a question from a false premise makes it difficult to answer.

Perhaps you could try to reformulate your question to ask something regarding the history of blasphemy as an interjection in English.

Next: [Words that express surprise disdain anger etc](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/536013/words-that-express-surprise-disdain-anger-etc)

This question asks for a list of words across a spectrum of emotional states. Such questions are usually off topic as there is no one correct answer. If you were searching for a specific word for use in a specific context then that would be OK.

If you really do want a list, you can consult a thesaurus (for example https://thesaurus.com), and you'll find lists of words that have similar meanings.

Thirdly: [How and Why Do Words Change?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/532371/how-and-why-do-words-change) [deleted]

This is a very broad question, as articulated by John Lawler. This site is not suitable for questions that could take an entire book to answer. Also, the question would be better suited to the http://linguistics.stackexchange.com site, because it applies to all languages, not just English. Although, again, it is too broad for that site to address adequately.

If there is something of more narrow focus about [semantic-shift](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/semantic-shift) in the English language that you'd like to know, I'm sure we have eager users dying to answer you.

I hope that was helpful.

Finally, some tips on asking questions here:

- We really like it when people research their questions and present their findings along with the question. We have a list of [commonly available reference works](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available) that can help. Also, the question might have already been asked, so be sure to [search](https://english.stackexchange.com/search) our archives, just in case.
- Keep the question focussed. A question asking for the history of the usage of a word in a given context is fine, but asking for all the different ways a word could be used is far too broad.
- Specifically for phrase or word requests: you must at least provide an example sentence. For these types of questions context is everything for getting to the best answer.

Comment: Measured tones indeed!