# Using internet search engines (Google/Yahoo) 'News' results to count frequency of a word

Tags: discussion, online-resources

I'm trying to find a way to export the results/ count the frequency of a specific word 'homeless' in News articles in my country over the past 10 years.

I am aware of Google Books NGram viewer for book results, but I need NEWSPAPERS only.
Other corpus sites such as Full Text Corpus data change large amounts for this work. Is there no free alternative? Or easy DIY way to export Google results? (I have tried this with no success).

Comment: What about https://elephind.com/

Comment: Are you North American or British? If the former, try [Chronicling America](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/)  from the Library of Congress archives. If British, that might be more difficult, but try [BNA](https://www.britishnewspaperarchive.co.uk/)

Comment: Welcome - I'm not sure why people are voting to close this. It seems legit. P.S. It doesn't help if you say "my country", we don't know what your country is!

Comment: You need to read this https://corpus.byu.edu/coca/compare-bnc.asp  It describes using COCA and BNC. There a keywords that allow you to specify that you are interested in *newspapers*

Comment: @chaslyfromUK It is a legitimate question, but, as a request for a resource, it belongs on English Meta (where it was just migrated to with my final vote).

Comment: You're not likely to get good answers if you are asking about a mysterious "my country".

Answer (score 5):

I've collated sites from the comments, and added one more. It's not clear to me how many of these include actual word-frequency counts.

- [Elephind](https://elephind.com/): Search the world's historical newspaper archives.
- [Chronicling America](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/): Search America's historic newspaper pages from 1789-1963 or use the U.S. Newspaper Directory to find information about American newspapers published between 1690-present.
- [The British Newspaper Archive](https://www.britishnewspaperarchive.co.uk/): The British Newspaper Archive is a partnership between the British Library and findmypast to digitise up to 40 million newspaper pages from the British Library's vast collection over the next 10 years.
- [NOW Corpus](https://www.english-corpora.org/now/): The NOW corpus (News on the Web) contains 10.4 billion words of data from web-based newspapers and magazines from 2010 to the present time.

Comment: Nice collections! Add this to the big meta question on resources.

Comment: @Mitch If you're talking about [What good reference works on English are available?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2573/291924), I've added those that are new to it.

Comment: Yep, that's the one. Thanks!