# List of English word research tools

Tags: discussion, resources

I once discovered a post on this site that had a very comprehensive list of English word research tools, but I am having difficulties finding it again.  Apologies for a potentially off-topic or closable question, but could someone help link the post?

I was inspired by a recent post which included the Google Ngram tool - very fascinating!

Thank you.

Comment: Possibly this one: https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available

Comment: If it is, then we can mark this question as a duplicate of that one because the title here is a useful pointer.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Many thanks ~~ feel free to do as you will with the question, I had looked and couldn't find it - but the link you provided is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks again.