# Can you recommend some books on recreational wordplay, like Alphabet Avenue?

Tags: discussion

So far, I have found these:

1. The Game of Words by Espy
2. Alphabet Avenue
3. The Dictionary of wordplay by Dave Morice

Are there other books like these? Not necessarily in English, other languages (French, Spanish etc) are good too.

Comment: Please read about types of questions we work with here: https://english.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not covered here (though it doesn't belong on Meta either).

Comment: With the exception of [softwarerecs.se], **no** Stack Exchange site will *recommend* anything. That's inherently opinion-based. We have a question on English-language [reference works](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2573), but you're not asking for reference works. The question **might** fit on [Language Learning](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), but do check first.