# Can we migrate 'Is there any online tool to read (pronounce) IPA and APA written words?' and its like to Meta?

Tags: support, feature-request, migration

[This](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/264239/is-there-any-online-tool-to-read-pronounce-ipa-and-apa-written-words) question (Is there any online tool to read (pronounce) IPA and APA written words?) has 105k views and 83 upvotes. But it's been closed because it's asking for a resource. Most resource requests are migrated to Meta because they're not actually about the English language itself. Fair enough, but let's do the same to this one, too. It looks like it was closed twice with the comment "*I'm voting to close this question because it belongs on ELU.Meta*".

Yesterday, I made a [trivial edit](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/264239/revisions) and submitted it for review with the edit summary '*Let's migrate this to EL&U Meta (through review or by opening and reclosing with a different reason)*'. It was [left closed in review](https://english.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/443175), after which it was re-opened and then protected by [@Cascabel_StandWithUkraine_](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/160305/cascabel-standwithukraine), who left a [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/264239/is-there-any-online-tool-to-read-pronounce-ipa-and-apa-written-words#comment1536573_264239):

> I voted to re-open so that the Q could get moved to meta, but apparently, that is no longer possible due to age. Perhaps a friendly mod could migrate it?

None of the mods, friendly or not, is @-pingable on that thread, so here's a meta-request for more visibility.

And while we're at it, can you mods migrate some of the other questions in the [online-resources](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online-resources) tag if it's possible and you'd feel it prudent?

- [English synonym online database?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16939/english-synonym-online-database) (3k views)
- [Which thesaurus best describes the differences between several similar words?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24423/which-thesaurus-best-describes-the-differences-between-several-similar-words) (3k views)
- [Is there such a thing as an idiom thesaurus that delivers synonymous phrases?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/93163/is-there-such-a-thing-as-an-idiom-thesaurus-that-delivers-synonymous-phrases) (17k views)
- [Is there an "article searcher" for a certain list of words?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/537099/is-there-an-article-searcher-for-a-certain-list-of-words) (meh)
- [Dictionary of English constructions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/194084/dictionary-of-english-constructions) (2k views)
- [Order of definitions in dictionaries](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/85058/order-of-definitions-in-dictionaries) (8k views)
- [What online resource can I use to find sentences that use a word in a specific part of speech?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/233931/what-online-resource-can-i-use-to-find-sentences-that-use-a-word-in-a-specific-p) (1k views)
- [Any online tool that highlights what grammatical case each word in a sentence belongs to?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/597062/any-online-tool-that-highlights-what-grammatical-case-each-word-in-a-sentence-be) (meh)
- [Does an online tool exist that can find words of a certain length given an input of certain characters?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23322/does-an-online-tool-exist-that-can-find-words-of-a-certain-length-given-an-input) (3k views)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Too old to migrate", unfortunately, all of them, even for elected mods.

Perhaps, the SE staff mods could, but unlikely they would.

You are welcome to incorporate any useful data from those into our [list of resources](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2573/50044) wiki on meta.

Further reading: [What is migration and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10249/309993)

> After 60 days, migrations can only be performed by Stack Exchange employees. These are performed only in very, *very* rare procedural cases and are usually not done on request.

Comment: How unfortunate. I doubt these are grave enough to merit CM involvement, so I guess they'll just have to stay on the main site.

Comment: @Heartspring The answers could be reproduced on Meta (you know, copy + paste). We have a [FAQ](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2573/191178) — some of these resources are already listed there.