# Where can I find books from the late 17th/early 18th century about English grammar and phonology?

Tags: discussion, resources

I'm interested in finding books that explain English grammar (as much of it and in as much depth as possible), written by scholars from the late 17th/early 18th century. Which do you recommend? Could you please provide a link e.g. to a pdf, where they can be read online?

I found three books from this period: Joseph Aickin's *The English grammar* (1693), Guy Miège's *The English grammar* (1688), and Christopher Cooper's *Grammatica Linguae Anglicanae* (1685), but I couldn't find them online. Could you please provide links to where I can read them, preferably the original versions, rather than reprints?

I'm also interested in finding books about English phonology, likewise written by English late 17th/early 18th century scholars. Could you please recommend some, and provide links to them (preferably original versions)? If books about English phonology didn't exist then, please provide links to phonology books that are as close to that time period as possible. Many thanks!

Comment: [There is a Wikipedia article on this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_English_grammars)

Comment: Are you more interested in references written -at that time- (ca 1700) about the contemporary state of affairs, or are you more interested in current (early 21st c) accounts of the ~1700 time period? My impression is that you are asking for the former, but those are likely not to be as scientifically robust as the latter. ie I don't think the science of phonology or syntax was very well developed around 1700.

Comment: @StuartF Thanks, I know, that is where I found the three grammars that I mentioned. Now I'm trying to find the actual text, as well as some more recommendation on books, and books about phonology. Do you know where I can find the actual books as PDF?

Comment: @Mitch Correct, I am more interested in 1690s-1700s books about the grammar and phonology at that time, written by scholars from that time, even though it was less developed. Do you know where I can find some PDFs?

Comment: See also: [What good reference works on English are available? Section: **Historical Resources**](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available/9879#9879)

Comment: Google Books makes a 1685 edition of [Cooper's _Grammatica_](https://books.google.com/books?id=rrIB-jAZugsC&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22Grammatica+Linguae%22+Cooper&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjY963pj8b_AhUOAjQIHfquBb4QuwV6BAgFEAY#v=onepage&q=%22Grammatica%20Linguae%22%20Cooper&f=false) available to read in its entirety. The book is written in Latin.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thanks!

Comment: @SvenYargs Thanks! Just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

Although Google Books and Hathitrust report multiple copies of both Aickin's grammar and Miège's grammar, none of the copies are available for reading in full on those sites. It is unclear to me what theory of copyright applies to books written more than 300 years ago, but evidently these sites are sufficiently cowed by some claimant to refrain from including readable copies of either book.

On the other hand  a number seventeenth- and early eighteenth-century books that address English grammar (as the term was then understood) either centrally or tangentially are available online. Here, arranged chronologically, are some that may be of interest to you:

- Brinsley, [*Ludus Literarius: Or, The Grammar Schoole*](https://books.google.com/books?id=53cWAAAAIAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22Brinsley%22+grammar&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwinj_n2ksb_AhX5PkQIHXJrDn0Q6AF6BAgDEAI#v=onepage&q=%22Brinsley%22%20grammar&f=false) (1627)
- Butler, [*The English Grammar, or The Institution of Letters, Syllables, and Words, in the English Tongue*](https://books.google.com/books?id=SnySAt0gM8IC&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22english+grammar%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjVzbiGiMb_AhXGMDQIHU6lCkMQ6AF6BAgEEAI#v=onepage&q=%22english%20grammar%22&f=false) (1633)
- Jonson, [*The English Grammar*](https://books.google.com/books?id=nVxRAAAAcAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22english+grammar%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwir0M3misb_AhUoBDQIHZ-EB9g4ChDoAXoECA8QAg#v=onepage&q=%22english%20grammar%22&f=false) (1640)
- Daines, [*Orthoepia Anglicana: or, the First Principall Part of the English Grammar, Teaching the Art of Right Speaking and Pronouncing English*](https://books.google.com/books?id=tsQxAAAAMAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22Orthoepia+Anglicana%22+Daines&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiQjqSilMb_AhVHBDQIHY6XA6gQuwV6BAgFEAg#v=onepage&q=%22Orthoepia%20Anglicana%22%20Daines&f=false) (1640) [English text begins after an 88-page introduction in German]
- Wharton, [*The English-grammar, or, The Institution of Letters, Syllables, and Words in the English-tongue*](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo2/A65598.0001.001/1:5?ALLSELECTED=1;c=eebo;c=eebo2;g=eebogroup;rgn=div1;singlegenre=All;sort=datea;subview=detail;type=simple;view=fulltext;xc=1;q1=English+Grammar) (1654) [Early English Books Online transcription]
- Fox, [*A Battle-Door for Teachers & Professors to Learn Singular & Plural You to Many, and Thou to One, Singular One, Thou, Plural Many, You*](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo/A40123.0001.001/1:3?c=eebo;c=eebo2;g=eebogroup;rgn=div1;view=fulltext;xc=1;q1=English+Grammar) (1660) [Early English Books Online transcription]
- Howell, [*A New English Grammar*](https://books.google.com/books?id=NE1gAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA21&dq=%22english+grammar%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi_7o6njMb_AhXaEDQIHUg4By84ZBDoAXoECAsQAg#v=onepage&q=%22english%20grammar%22&f=false) (1662)
- Walker, [*A Treatise of English Particles: Shewing Much of the Variety of Their Significations and Uses in English*](https://books.google.com/books?id=eP1mAAAAcAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22treatise+of+English+particles%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjHzeW__Mb_AhU7HTQIHXAZD10Q6AF6BAgJEAI#v=onepage&q=%22treatise%20of%20English%20particles%22&f=false) (1663)
- Wilkins, [*An Essay Towards a Real Character, and a Philosophical Language*](https://books.google.com/books?id=BCCtZjBtiEYC&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22Essay+Towards+a+Real+Character%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjYj_-J5Mb_AhUdIDQIHdfNCtoQ6AF6BAgJEAI#v=onepage&q=%22Essay%20Towards%20a%20Real%20Character%22&f=false) (1668)
- Strong, [*England's Perfect School-Master: or, Directions for Exact Spelling, Reading, and Writing*](https://books.google.com/books?id=rZhkAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA4&dq=%22England%27s+perfect+school-master%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjt1o_P_cb_AhUAIDQIHYAKDRUQ6AF6BAgJEAI#v=onepage&q=%22England%27s%20perfect%20school-master%22&f=false) (1676)
- Dalgarno, [*Didascalocophus, or the Deaf and Dumb Mans Tutor, to which is added a Discourse of the Nature of Double Consonants*](https://books.google.com/books?id=TepmAAAAcAAJ&pg=PP11&dq=%22Didascalocophus%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjq0Zrk2cb_AhUOHDQIHdANDfwQ6AF6BAgHEAI#v=onepage&q=%22Didascalocophus%22&f=false) (1680)
- [*The Compendious School-Master: Teaching the English-Tongue*](https://books.google.com/books?id=f_pmAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA5&dq=grammar+%22english+tongue%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjZ8bqX4sb_AhUDIX0KHUf4D344KBDoAXoECAEQAg#v=onepage&q=grammar%20%22english%20tongue%22&f=false) (1687)
- Miège, [*The English Grammar*](https://books.google.com/books?id=58BZAAAAMAAJ&dq=%22Mi%C3%A8ge%22&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22particles%22) (1688) [searchable snippet view only]
- Jones, [*Practical Phonography: Or, the New Art of Rightly Speling and Writing Words by the Sound Thereof*](https://books.google.com/books?id=gmwCAAAAQAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22Practical+phonography%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj3g4iF-8b_AhUsADQIHU8-DzEQ6AF6BAgIEAI#v=onepage&q=%22Practical%20phonography%22&f=false) (1701)
- A.N., [*The English Scholar Compleat*](https://books.google.com/books?id=HxFNAAAAcAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22english+grammar%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwir0M3misb_AhUoBDQIHZ-EB9g4ChDoAXoECAgQAg#v=onepage&q=%22english%20grammar%22&f=false) (1706)
- Greenwood, [*An Essay Towards a Practical English Grammar*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/An_essay_towards_a_practical_English_Gra/arJWAAAAcAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22english+grammar%22&pg=PA36&printsec=frontcover) (1711)
- Brightland, [*A Grammar of the English Tongue*](https://books.google.com/books?id=ql1iAAAAcAAJ&pg=PP16&dq=grammar+%22english+tongue%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwin6Iun4Mb_AhXvGzQIHdV9AQU4ChDoAXoECAYQAg#v=onepage&q=grammar%20%22english%20tongue%22&f=false), third edition (1711)
- Swift, [*A Proposal for Correcting, Improving and Ascertaining the English Tongue*](https://books.google.com/books?id=5FMJAAAAQAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=grammar+%22english+tongue%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwin6Iun4Mb_AhXvGzQIHdV9AQU4ChDoAXoECAkQAg#v=onepage&q=grammar%20%22english%20tongue%22&f=false), second edition (1712)
- [*Bellum Grammaticale: or The Grammatical Battel Royal*](https://books.google.com/books?id=hbNWAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA1&dq=%22Bellum+Grammaticale%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiFgu674cb_AhVDIX0KHT4NCnoQ6AF6BAgEEAI#v=onepage&q=%22Bellum%20Grammaticale%22&f=false) (1712)
- Maittaire, [*The English Grammar: Or, An Essay on the Art of Grammar*](https://books.google.com/books?id=0UkDfyq0NJsC&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22english+grammar%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwir0M3misb_AhUoBDQIHZ-EB9g4ChDoAXoECAsQAg#v=onepage&q=%22english%20grammar%22&f=false) (1712)
- Elstob, [*The Rudiments of Grammar for the English-Saxon Tongue*](https://books.google.com/books?id=FodFAAAAcAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=Rudiments+of+English+Grammar+Elstob&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwihjKu1-cb_AhXFATQIHTg1CUsQ6AF6BAgGEAI#v=onepage&q=%22Rudiments%20of%20Grammar%22&f=false) (1715)
- Greenwood, [*An Essay Towards a Practical English Grammar*](https://books.google.com/books?id=kLJWAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA79&dq=%22nary+a%22+or&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjhho25zOTrAhXmHjQIHXyaBqgQ6AEwAHoECAEQAg#v=onepage&q=%22nary%20a%22%20or&f=false) (1729)
- Low, [*English Grammar Reformd into a Small Compass and Easy Method*](https://books.google.com/books?id=vUZgAAAAcAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22english+grammar%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjVzbiGiMb_AhXGMDQIHU6lCkMQ6AF6BAgDEAI#v=onepage&q=%22english%20grammar%22&f=false) (1732)
- Greenwood, [*The Royal English Grammar: Containing What Is Necessary to the Knowledge of the English Tongue*](https://books.google.com/books?id=m29XAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22english+grammar%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwir0M3misb_AhUoBDQIHZ-EB9g4ChDoAXoECAwQAg#v=onepage&q=%22english%20grammar%22&f=false) (1737)

Comment: Thank you so much, that is invaluable!

Answer (score 3):

*[The Rudiments of English Grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Rudiments_of_English_Grammar)* by Joseph Priestly, first published in 1761

This pdf version, edition 1772, is downloadable from [Archive.org](https://archive.org/details/rudimentsenglis00priegoog/page/n3/mode/2up?view=theater)

*[The Royal English Grammar: Containing what is Necessary to the Knowledge of the English Tongue](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Dictionary_of_National_Biography,_1885-1900/Greenwood,_James)* by James Greenwood. First published in 1711; 2nd edition, 1722; 3rd edition, 1729; the 4th edition, 1737, is in the link below.

This version is also [downloadable from Archive.org](https://archive.org/details/royalenglishgra00greegoog/page/n16/mode/2up)

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to be of service :)