# What differences are between general-purpose and Learner's dictionaries?

Tags: discussion

https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2574/ says

> General-purpose dictionaries
>
> The online dictionaries listed here are broadly suitable for native
> speakers, providing major definitions and examples, pronunciations
> (including audio), basic etymology, and some usage notes.
>
> Learner's dictionaries
>
> [A learner's dictionary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monolingual_learner%27s_dictionary) is geared to the needs of people learning
> English as a foreign or second language, for example, by providing
> notes on usage and common errors.

I was wondering what differences in features are between general-purpose and Learner's dictionaries? [My internet access is restricted](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/87507/website-for-indirectly-downloading-a-webpage), and can't access a lot of sites, notably Wikipedia.