# Looking for an online tool which provides a frequency of usage of any search phrase/sentence provided using large corpus of online text

Tags: support, online-resources

I am looking for an online service which provides the frequency of a search phrase across all the literature in English that there is. Hopefully billions of lines of text. For example, if the phrase is "cat on a tin roof" then example output could be found 725,819 times. And then a list of documents where it is used as the outcome.

The frequency value is useful for me when writing as I could use phrases which are more popular and in many cases can see examples of popular usage. I know that such a tool exists as it was used by a former colleague who was writing a PhD thesis. But I do not recall the name of the online service.

Comment: You mean [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/)?

Comment: I know Ngrams, and probably the said tool uses that under the hood, but I am looking for a service which supports me in writing.  Suppose I want to see the usage of "This painting is not good" across all the text and then based on its popularity I would use that sentence in my work. If the sentence I construct is not correct, it is likely to be used less often. Google Ngrams does not do this, to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: This belongs on meta.

Comment: Have you seen our [list of corpora](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2578/18696)?

Comment: I think your approach is flawed.  If the corpus is of spoken English, it won't be suitable for expository prose much of the time; and if it is of written texts, unless you have a way of filtering by genre, the register could be inappropriate for the text you are writing. There's really no substitute for reading and learning.

Comment: Unfortunately, even in a corpus of the entire searchable internet, you'll get very few hits even for grammatical utterances that are long or very specific. For example, the 7-gram "We did go to the shore but..." returns no hits even though it's perfectly grammatical. Corpus research gets around this restriction somewhat by using advanced search, such as a search for `PRON DO` followed by `but` (possible in COCA if it doesn't time out), but knowing what to search for and how to interpret the results is its own area of expertise.

Comment: @TimR and Laurel,  You are right. But I am interested in technical writing and most of the sentences I use would have a high probability of being already used.  I agree with what you say, but I could then search for "go to the shore" which will have higher hits. As a learner, I am not looking for just grammatical correctness, there are other tools for that. I want to write text which is understood with little effort and goes easy on the reader.

Comment: @kosmos: You seem to have a good command of the language already, so that future acquisition should be swift. I don't know of a corpus of technical documents in any case.  But you could type a phrase into Google and use the "Books" filter.