# Recommend the best book for articles

Tags: discussion

Can you recommend the best book on English grammar articles?

The indefinite and definite articles a, an, and the?

Comment: Have you searched our [list of resources](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2573/50044)?

Comment: What do you mean by *articles*? An *article* is [a particular thing](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2031/are-there-any-simple-rules-for-choosing-the-definite-vs-indefinite-vs-none-a) in English grammar. However, we don't generally give recommendations, because they are opinions, the books may not actually suit **you, and** they go out of date.

Comment: The definite and indefinite articles A,an and the?